# Correct BIOS configuration for a Gigabyte Windows 10 Pro USB installation

Tags: windows-10, bios, troubleshooting

Trying to install Windows 10 Pro using the USB thumb drive that came directly from Microsoft. It is how they distributed the OS for retail sale.

This is a new system with a Gigabyte motherboard (model GA-Z270M-D3H) and a Crucial SSD as SATA0.

When I turn on the machine, the Gigabyte splash screen appears but nothing else happens. It just sits there.

I've taken a picture of my BIOS settings. I've never worked with Gigabyte before, only ASUS. Do I have the boot sequence set up correctly?
[image: Gigabyte BIOS boot sequence screencapture]

P.S. When I turn off CSM, save and exit, not even the Gigabyte splash screen appears, just a blank screen. Had to clear CMOS using the jumpers.

P.P.S. Choosing boot option #1 (UEFI:... MSFTWindows 10 PMAP Partition1) from the Boot Menu does nothing; the Gigabyte splash screen remains. Choosing boot option #2 (KDI-MSFTWindows 10 PMAP) results in `BOOTMGR image corrupt` error.  Microsoft tech support says "that's a problem with the M/B".  Gigabyte tech support advised to "download the ISO and use Media Creation Tool".

Comment: Turn off CSM support first of all. Then save and reboot and see how the options have changed. How did you make the bootable USB? It should’ve been with the Windows media creation tool.

Comment: The USB drive came directly from Microsoft. It is how they distributed the O/S.

Comment: I have turned off CSM support, saved and exited, and now there's just a blank screen, not even the Gigabyte splash screen.

Comment: @mrblint - What storage devices do you have installed?  Edit your question instead of submitting additional comments.

Comment: Please update your BIOS settings screen. I’m curious how the options have changed. CSM boot isn’t needed.

Comment: After turning off CSM it is no longer possible to get back into the BIOS  :(    I'm trying to press F12 and DEL, but the BIOS never appears. Just a blank screen.

Comment: Here's a report of a similar problem. What does the answerer mean by "pull the fury card"? https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/disabled-csm-no-post.2791219/  It looks as though I will have to figure out how to "reset the BIOS via jumpers".

Comment: What is the specific model of the mainboard?

Comment: @Moab: Thanks for taking a look. Question edited to supply that detail: GA-Z270M-D3H.

Comment: Maybe some insight in the motherboard manual....https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z270M-D3H-rev-10#support-manual